# Performing calculations when inserting in MySQL

Tags: mysql, calculated-columns

The scenario im facing is given below:

```
Table 1:

ID   Name   Age1
1     X      22
2     Y      23
```

Table 2:

```
ID   Name   Age2
1     XX     45
2     YY     55
```

I need to add a new column in Table 1 which is equal to

```
(TABLE1.AGE1/TABLE2.AGE2) * 100
```

Can I perform this using MySQL?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: yes, you can. what had you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Introduce the column, then add the data. Something like

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD Ratio double NULL AFTER Age1;
UPDATE Table1, Table2 
  SET  Table1.Ratio = (Table1.Age1/Table2.Age2) * 100 
  WHERE Table1.ID = Table2.ID
```

You can't do it with a single query.

Comment: Thank you utkuerd. I just tried your solution and it worked like a charm. Thank you for your valuable input.